# multiple condition in while loop not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a while loop with multiple AND condition. But the loop only take into account the first condition and not the rest. Should i do it the other way? Could anyone help me on this matter.

```
operator = UserForm_Finish.ComboBox1.Value
machine = UserForm_Finish.ComboBox2.Value
qty_prod = UserForm_Finish.TextBox1.Value
step = UserForm_Finish.ComboBox3.Value

t_finish = Now()

j = 2

While Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, 1).Value <> operator And Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, 2).Value <> machine And Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, 5).Value <> step
j = j + 1
    If j = 80 Then
       MsgBox ("There is an error")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Wend

t_start = Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, 10).Value
duration = t_finish - t_start
Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, 11).Value = t_finish
Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, 12).Value = duration
Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, 13).Value = qty_prod

Example of data :

Before entering qty produced

Operator  Machine  Step  Qty produced
1.Kevin   Grind    P74   70
2.Kevin   Grind    P75   

After entering qty produced. The loop should find the same operator name, machine and step in order to place the qty produced at the right line.

Example of wrong output

After entering qty produced. exmple if qty prod is 55. Here is the output

Operator  Machine  Step  Qty produced
1.Kevin   Grind    P74   55
2.Kevin   Grind    P75   

its replace the qty produced from line 1 and not 2.

Desired output :

Operator  Machine  Step  Qty produced
1.Kevin   Grind    P74   70
2.Kevin   Grind    P75   55
```

I've added some wrong output received.

Comment: The `And` function does work just fine for me. What exactly do you experience? Sidenote: Don't name your variables the same as known vba syntax, for example: The `Step` keyword.

Comment: I have several values which are operator name, machine used, step number and quantity produced. This will be fill out by the user. The objective is to associate the quantity produced to another worksheet if they have the same operator name, machine used and the step number. The problem i'm having is that, when the first test result is true, it doesn't take into account the second and third test. And associate it to the wrong rows

Comment: Because all three conditions need to be true in order to place the quantity produced at the right cell.  for example, they are duplicate of operator name in the worksheet, and if the first condition is true, it supposed to verify the second and third condition but thats not the case. Instead, it place the quantity produced at the very first operator name found.

Comment: Trailing/leadng spaces? Invisible characters? Or just the wrong understanding of what the "<>" operator does? Without sample data we cannot reproduce a fine working `And` function that wouldn't work as expected on your end.

Comment: i've edited the post

Comment: Are you refering to the correct columns?

Comment: Yes. I've checked several times and even try to use IF condition but the same problem occurs

Comment: If you want to check that all 3 conditions matches, you need to use `AND`. But if you want to check that any of the 3 conditions *doesn't* match, you need to use `OR`

Comment: Thats the reason why i used AND instead of OR. Because every condition need to be true first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical error in the code. From your description of the error, you want to find the row that has a matching `operator` and a matching `machine` and a matching `step` so that you can fill in the produced quantity.

You are however, checking for an inequality of the fields, which changes the logic: You want to discard a row if any of the fields is different.

To correct:

Alternative A: In the while loop, you can continue to use the inequality (<>) test but change  to use the `Or` operator.

Alternative B: Or, you can change the while loop to check for equality (=) and continue to use the `And` operator.